# Problems with Wi-Fi speed on Ubuntu 22.04 when using WPA3-Personal encryption in the router settings

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, wpa2, wpa3

I use Wi-Fi 5G on the same device but on different OS. In Windows, both with WPA3 and WPA2 encryptions, the Internet speed is about 250 Mbps. But on Ubuntu, the network speed with WPA3 encryption drops to 20-30 Mbps, although if I switch to WPA2 encryption the speed return to 250 Mbps .
In my Ubuntu the network settings already have WPA3 encryption

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please provide more information about your wireless device. As a general rule, you can run the [wireless info script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/) and then provide a link to the pastebin of the output and this should give us all the scrubbed info needed to diagnose the issue.